# Qt PushButton Checkable

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I am using Qt Designer to create a user interface.
Everything was fine until I included a stylesheet.
When I press a button it remains pressed, even though `checkable` is set to false. 
Also, one of the buttons appears to be pressed when I open the UI even though `autoDefault` is also set to false.
If I remove the stylesheet, these things don't happen anymore, as expected.

This is the first time I'm using stylesheets in Qt Designer, so maybe I have missed something that might introduce this behavior.

edit: Here is the part of the stylesheet for the pushbuttons:

```
.QPushButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0  #85335C, stop: 0.12 #944D70, stop: 0.49 #5C002E);
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 25px;  
}
```

Comment: Including part of the stylesheet you are using might help here (the part that sets the style for the pushbutton!). Have you taken a look at the examples? (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet-examples.html)

Answer (score 4):

The presence of a stylesheet often must override any native platform styling. If the stylesheet modifies anything but margins, the platform styling must be suppressed, since the platform styles do not support styling. Thus, when you have a stylesheet, you must style everything on a given control on your own: all states, etc.